# Does the C# compiler optimize foreach blocks when its contents have the Conditional attribute?

Tags: c#, debugging, compiler-optimization

I'm writing some debug code at work, and I'm wondering if what I'm doing might hurt performance or not.

Let's get to the code:

```
foreach (var item in aCollection)
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
```

I know that the Debug class uses the Conditional attribute to avoid compilation in release mode (or whenever DEBUG is undefined), but would this end up as a futile/empty iteration when compiled in release mode or would it be optimized by the compiler?

Comment: I would guess that it would not be optimized away, as there are other side effects in enumerating a collection.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, is that a guess or are you sure? What would be the side effects in enumerating a collection?

Comment: It is a guess; but I am virtually certain the **C# compiler** will not optimize away the loop (whether the JIT compiler does is another question).  All method calls (e.g., `GetEnumerator()`, `MoveNext()`) are side effects, as are all array accesses.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I don't think reading from a (non-`null`) array from a valid index has side effects.

Comment: @svick ~~What if the array reference is `null`?~~ Got your edit in before my comment!

Comment: Hmm... You're right. Unless the optimizer takes into account that all those are triggered with the intention of doing a pointless enumeration. I will make a simple test to verify this. Also, if you are right, you gave the correct answer first. Make a proper response so I can give you the points :)

Comment: @MikeStrobel I guess that might be the only case, but that can still be optimized as a single `null` check instead of iterating the whole array.

Comment: @GuillermoAres Added a formal answer.  Thanks!  (Also, I did my own test, both with and without `null` checks, and in no case did the C# 5 compiler omit the enumeration).

Comment: Yeahp, I tried it out and it seems that the enumeration is being done anyway (at least when using a List). Doing the "foreach Debug.WriteLine()" for a list with 10k elements takes 2296 milliseconds when in debug, 0.0896 in release, and 0.008 if you literally remove the enumeration code. Mike, post a proper response so I can give you the points!

Comment: waiting for [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **C# compiler** will not optimize away the enumeration because the act of enumerating over a collection may produce side effects:

1. In the case of an array, the act of indexing into the array implies a side effect (and the C# compiler rewrites `foreach` loops over arrays into indexing loops).
2. For other collections, the calls to `GetEnumerator()` and `MoveNext()` imply side effects.

In both cases, the potential `null` dereference is a side effect.

When invoking a `[Conditional]` method, only the method call and its formal arguments will be omitted from the compiled code.  Note that even arguments *with side effects* would be omitted.  However, no *surrounding code* would be omitted.

My own tests show that even adding an explicit `null` check will not coax the C# compiler into optimizing away the enumeration, even for a simple array.

Whether the **JIT compiler** optimizes away the enumeration code is another question.  It might, if it can prove that the collection is always non-`null` **and** that there are no other meaningful side effects.  The JIT *might* be sophisticated enough to do this for arrays; I wouldn't bet on it, though.  If the added overhead concerns you, place the enumeration code within an `#if` region as @pid suggests.

Comment: `"the act of enumerating over a collection [may] produce side effects"`  It's *possible* for there to be side effects.  It's not a guarantee that there will be side effects.  Of course, since the compiler/runtime don't know if there will be side effects or not, they cannot omit the code either way.

Comment: @Servy: Fair enough.  Wording changed.

Answer (score 7):

You are not leveraging any compiler symbols here. Wrap it inside these:

```
#if DEBUG

    // your code here

#endif
```

Advantages of this approach:

- readability is greatly decreased by the `[Conditional]` method attribute. It is not obvious on the invoking side that an invocation will not take place in the compiled code. Teams should refrain from that practice in favor of more explicit conditional compilation methods. Even commenting is not advisable because there's always that *someone* in large teams who forgets to comment stuff like this. The example above, instead, is easy to read (VS2010+ even shades the text when it is not part of the current build profile).
- constructing collections might be *very* expensive (e.G. constructing 1000 items with data from a database). In those cases compiler symbols allow for easier and cleaner culling of the interested code, without leaving an empty loop or the construction of the collection.

Comment: @Gusdor: You, sir, saved me from stumbling over that unforgiveable language-transfer typo. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's right, I'm not using compiler symbols, but the Debug class methods are flagged [Condition("DEBUG")], which means that the calls made to those method will not be compiled. Hence, the code would end up as Alberto and Mike pointed out.

Comment: Personally, I find the Debug class particularly "readable", as it is a wide-spread debugging tool and, sooner or later, every C# developer should get to know it fairly well. I sometimes use the #if DEBUG notation, but I find it pretty annoying since VS doesn't seem to like it to follow the general indexing rules/conventions and... Well, I really don't like "if" statements in OO code, even if it is a compiler directive. I'm thinking in implementing an extension method for the Debug class, such as "Do(Action anAction)" with the Conditional("DEBUG") attribute. I think it can result pretty clean.

Comment: Meh, Debug is sealed :/. Now that's an annoying C# feature.

Answer (score 4):

That foreach will not be wiped away.

The compiled code will be something like:

```
foreach (var item in aCollection)
{
   ;
}
```

the collection will be enumerated anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler optimize this by completely removing the enumeration code?

Comment: The C# compiler would not.  The JIT might if, for example, the collection is an array, and it can prove that the array will never be `null`.  But I would not count on the JIT being that sophisticated.